# In a Visual Studio C# Console Application do dll files include their dependencies installed

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

let's say I have a dll called Tuna.dll and in that dll I have a class named Tuna which is dependent on another class in another dll called Pork.dll. If I then use Tuna.dll in a new project as a dependency would I also have to find Pork.dll or will Pork.dll already be included with Tuna.dll? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It depends on how you add the dll to your project. Do you use nuget, project reference, or do you manually edit the csproj file with a direct dll reference to a file path or GAC?

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks for the response. In this case the dll is added by project reference. In Visual Studio this translates to right clicking the dependencies -> Add Project Reference -> Browsing for the Dll

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding references to DLLs then you typically have to add them both. If you are referring to other projects in the same solution (normally this is a better approach) then the dependency chain should work itself out automatically.

Comment: If both projects have to communicate with each other then would that be an issue or require some kind of api?

Comment: No, either way one project would reference the other, and then can use classes from it. There is no special API - the "API" is whatever public classes you define in the project yourself.  The advantage of keeping both projects in the same solution is that things will automatically be recompiled when changes are made, and its much less likely to have a problem where you are using an older, compiled DLL instead of the newest actual code.

Comment: Back to the DLL question, what is the standard to keeping DLLs in a project using Visual Studio? I have them in a folder but every time I load the repository to a new computer I have to add the dependencies on Visual Studio even though the folder still exists.

Comment: I recommend using the Visual Studio default settings for this, so you will end up with a `project\bin\debug` folder for each project/DLL. If project A references project B, then in that debug folder you'll end up with copies of both A.dll and B.dll

Comment: The problem I have is that I wasnt given a project with the DLLs, they were just given to my by themselves. Should I just make a dummy class project with the DLLs with nothing but the DLLs?